# Get a list of materialized view log in oracle'

Tags: oracle11g, materialized-views

I want to get a list of materialized view logs in Oracle. How can I do that? I thought that this will give me a list:

```
 select * from USER_BASE_TABLE_MVIEWS;
```

When a materialized view log was dropped and recreated by using the script similar to this :

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "XXX"."STATUSES_AUD"
 PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 30 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 ....
```

It does not show up when this query is run :

```
select * from USER_BASE_TABLE_MVIEWS;
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`[dba_|all_|user_]mview_logs`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1103.htm#REFRN20137).  `dba_mview_logs` will show all the materialized view logs in the database but not everyone will have access to the `dba_` views.  You probably need `create any dictionary`.  `all_mview_logs` will show you all the materialized view logs that you have access to.  `user_mview_logs` will show you all the materialized view logs that you own.